# Declaring In-Line Secret Keys in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm learning Ruby On Rails.  I'm trying to use the aws-s3 gem to access Amazon S3.  One line of my controller code reads:

```
AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
      :access_key_id     => 'myrealaccesskeyishere',
      :secret_access_key => 'myrealsecretkeyishere'
)
```

I've noticed that if I make an error, sometimes rails will come back and show a few lines of code where it thinks the error might be.  Should I not be writing these out in the .rb controller files like this?  Am I potentially risking my secret key?  If so, how should I be doing this instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put this in an initializer. Place it in `config/intializers/amazon_s3.rb`

Is there a reason you are putting this code directly in the controller?

Comment: Like I said, I'm just learning, so I'm really not sure the best way to handle it.  I just put it in the controller, because that's the only place I need S3 access.  Am I risking my secret key using my current method?  Why is your method superior?

Comment: @GingerBreadMane - You aren't really "risking" your key, you are just making it more work on yourself later on. When you change your key, you will have to change it in a bunch of places. If you use an initializer, you only need to change it once. Also, should you not want to use amazon, you can remove the initializer, and won't have to update all your controllers.

Comment: Not to mention, if you put in a separate file you can change its permissions and remove it from version control and otherwise secure it.